# How do I fill in the BabeLua settings?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, lua, babelua

I want to be able to program LUA in Visual Studio 2013 Ultimate. I have BabeLua to try to do this. In the program there is a tab called settings. Within that tab there are 5 textboxes that I do not understand

LUA Scripts Folder -

Folder where the files are stored? (Documents/Visual Studio 2013/ Projects)?

Lua exe Path

Working Path

Command line

Setting Name

Can someone give me an explanation to all of these Fields?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

This prompt seems to be slightly different than the one I am seeing with the latest update of babelua, but regardless:

- **Lua scripts folder**: This should be the explicit path to some file folder where your script is located.
- **Lua exe path**: explicitly provide the path to your exe (which you can download from [here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/luabinaries/files/5.1.4/Executables/).

> **Note:** be sure to download the windows 32 Bit version, even if your machine happens to be 64 bit. There appears to be some sort of bug
>   that prevents Babelua from running in debug mode with the 64 bit
>   version.

- **Working path**: I just provide the same path to the folder containing the lua exe.
- **Command line**: This is where you provide the name of the script(s) you want to run. If you wrote a file in your project called "script.lua" you would provide the name of that file, with the extension, in this area.
- **Lua project name**: This is different than the "setting name" prompt you have, but its rather self-explanatory.

Example:

- **Lua scripts folder**: C:\Users\kevin1michael\Documents\LuaScripts
- **Lua exe path**: C:\Users\kevin1michael\Documents\Lua\32BitLua\lua5.1.exe
- **Working path**: C:\Users\kevin1michael\Documents\Lua\32BitLua
- **Command line**: script1.lua
- **Lua project name**: Project1