# What do I put for the Lua exe path when using Visual Studios babelua extension?

Tags: visual-studio, debugging, visual-studio-2013, scripting, lua

Every time I try to run my lua program in Visual Studios with the babelua extension a Debug window pops up that asks for the "Lua exe path" the "Working path" and the "Command line", what do I have to put in these to run the program? Sorry I would show a picture but I don't have a high enough reputation.

Comment: Lua must be installed separately (fill Lua install folder in "Lua exe path").  [Official site](https://babelua.codeplex.com/) and [install instructions](http://www.computercraft.info/forums2/index.php?/topic/21654-babelua-extension-for-visual-studio/) may be helpful.

Comment: ...Wow, thank you so much, I don't know why I didn't think of that

Comment: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27242639/how-do-i-fill-in-the-babelua-settings](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27242639/how-do-i-fill-in-the-babelua-settings) Thare is answer.
Good luck to your lua script